# ndk-build cannot find module with tag 'cxx-stl/system' in import path

Tags: android, android-ndk, android.mk

I am a new learner of Android and I'm trying an android ndk demo with Ubuntu.

I run ndk-build and get the result below.

```
andylee@ubuntu:~/Downloads/android-ndk-r11-linux-
x86_64.tar.bz2/sources/hello/jni$ ndk-build -C 
/home/andylee/Downloads/android-ndk-r11-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2/sources/hello
make: Entering directory '/home/andylee/Downloads/android-ndk-r11-linux-
x86_64.tar.bz2/sources/hello'
make: *** No rule to make target '/hello.c', needed by 
'obj/local/armeabi/objs/helloARM/hello.o'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory '/home/andylee/Downloads/android-ndk-r11-linux-
x86_64.tar.bz2/sources/hello'
```

Then I delete the Android.mk in another folder (the folder structure is below) and get this.

```
andylee@ubuntu:~$ ndk-build -C /home/andylee/Downloads/android-ndk-r11-
linux-x86_64.tar.bz2/sources/hello
make: Entering directory '/home/andylee/Downloads/android-ndk-r11-linux-
x86_64.tar.bz2/sources/hello'
Android NDK: : Cannot find module with tag 'cxx-stl/system' in import path    

Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined 
?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
Android NDK:         
/home/andylee/Downloads/android-ndk-r11-linux-
x86_64.tar.bz2/build/core/setup-toolchain.mk:213: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    
.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory '/home/andylee/Downloads/android-ndk-r11-linux-
x86_64.tar.bz2/sources/hello'
```

My folder structure is like this.

```
home/andylee/Downloads/android-ndk-r11-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
  ndk-build
  /sources  
    /cxx-stl
        /system
           /Android.mk
    /hello
        /jni
           /hello.c
           /hello.h
           /Android.mk
```

Android.mk in jni folder

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello.c 
LOCAL_MODULE := helloARM 
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -pie -fPIE 
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -pie -fPIE 
LOCAL_FORCE_STATIC_EXECUTABLE := true
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

hello.c

```
#include "hello.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
printf("Hello World!\n");
return 0;
}
```

hello.h

```
#ifndef HELLOHEADER_H_
#define HELLOHEADER_H_
#include <stdio.h>
#endif /*HELLOHEADER_H_*/
```

I wonder why ndk will find module with tag 'cxx-stl/system', I have not import any module in Android.mk. I've been frustrated with this for hours and I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried forcing a rebuild with `-B`?

Comment: I tried and get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is some syntax error when I copy those codes from the demo. After correcting the error I can successfully build.